# Bootstrap slider/carousel

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want to make a bootstrap carousel with text, on top of this 4 circles where everytime 1 circle is 'selected/hovered' the right circle and the right line underneath is shown. Something like this:
[image: Have a look here]

Who can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS carousel you can look at, however as others pointed out Stack Overflow is not a service to create your projects for you. You will need to research CSS more so you can get the carousel to appear how you would like.

```js
//Changed index so 1 is actually first image, rather than starting at 0 index
var index = 1;
var paused = false;
var slideShow = [];

for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow").length; i++) {
  slideShow[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("slideShow")[i];
  slideShow[i].style.display = "none";
}

slideShow[0].style.display = "inline";

var slides = setInterval(function() {
  if (index < slideShow.length) {
    index++;
    showDivs();
  }
  else {
    index = 1;
    showDivs();
  }
},1000);

function control(n) {
  clearInterval(slides);

  if (index+n > slideShow.length) {
    index = 1;
  }
  else if (index+n <= 0) {
    index = slideShow.length;
  }
  else {
    index += n;
  }
  showDivs();
}

function showDivs() {
  //Hide all slideShow elements, and then show only the targeted element
  for (let i=1; i<=slideShow.length; i++) {
    slideShow[i-1].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideShow[index-1].style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<button  onclick="control(-1)" class="arrows" id="left"><</button>
<p class="slideShow">1</p>
<p class="slideShow">2</p>
<p class="slideShow">3</p>
<p class="slideShow">4</p>
<p class="slideShow">5</p>
<button onclick="control(1)" class="arrows" id="right">></button>
```